# Create a Custom Group in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data that looks like this:

```
with t (ticket_number,source_person,relationship, destination_person) as (
  values
  (1 ,'Jim'  ,'Dad', 'Stan'),
  (1 ,'Stan','Son', 'Jim'),
  (1 ,'Jim' ,'Mom', 'Sue'),
  (1, 'Sue', 'Son', 'Jim'),
  (2, 'Larry', 'Brother', 'Earl')
  (2, 'Earl', 'Sister', 'Edna')
  (2, 'Sam', 'Sister', 'Jane'),
  (2, 'Jane', 'Sister', 'Sam')
)
select * from t
```

Basically, the first row is saying that Jim's Dad is Stan. The second row is saying that Stan's son is Jim, and so on.

I want to create a family id for each family/ticket combination. Not everyone on a ticket is part of a family, though. I need to be able to create a group that identifies a family within a ticket based on the relationships. Any ideas on how to do this? I could use row_number, but I don't know how to prevent the code from incrementing up when the "source person" was a previous "destination person". Help!

Desired outcome would look like this:

```
with desiredoutput (ticket_number,source_person,relationship, destination_person, familynumber) as (
  values
  (1 ,'Jim'  ,'Dad', 'Stan',1),
  (1 ,'Stan','Son', 'Jim',1),
  (1 ,'Jim' ,'Mom', 'Sue',1),
  (1, 'Sue', 'Son', 'Jim',1),
  (2, 'Larry', 'Brother', 'Earl',1)
  (2, 'Earl', 'Sister', 'Edna'1),
  (2, 'Sam', 'Sister', 'Jane',2),
  (2, 'Jane', 'Sister', 'Sam', 2)
)
select * from desiredoutcome
```

Comment: The term "family" is ambiguous. Please provide your desired output based on your sample data. You may need to add a few more rows to capture all your possible situations.

Comment: This is a Graph Partition problem. It's not trivial to resolve using pure SQL. Can be done -- in a rather inneficient way -- using arrays or varchars. Better do it in your app.

Comment: Desired outcome is updated. Basically, if the source person was previously a destination person, i want them in the same family. if not, i want a new family.

Comment: Desired outcome includes people not found in your sample data. Please correct one or the other. Also, desired outcome should not be a CTE but rather just a table.

Comment: Updated, so sorry